# Socialite laravel 5.4 Facebook Provider

Tags: facebook, laravel-5, laravel-socialite

i have a problem here maybe sameone can help me:  i install the Socialite pakcage  to my laravel project and in start it work perfect with facebook , google and linkedin provider. But now it get always this message when i try to connect with facebook , and other provider connect perfectly.

What's wrong ?

> ClientException in RequestException.php line 111:
>       Client error: `GET https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/me?access_token=&fields=name,email,gender,verified,link&appsecret_proof=5fbda0d218f94cb8024712269c053f0186d360efd82cd358b588eaf621e0c79c`
>   resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
>       {"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthExce (truncated...)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I fix the problem !
You need the make same changes in vendor/laravel/socialite/src/Two/FacebookProvider.php file

See here:

[github socialite](https://github.com/laravel/socialite/pull/214/files)

Comment: Actually the best way is to run `composer require laravel/socialite` again and it will install the latest version including the fix

Answer (score 3):

composer update will fix it by updating the laravel/socialite version

Answer (score -1):

Oh, so I'm not the only one. Good. Waiting on the answer, I've lost like at least 60mins trying to figure this out, I'm quite sure it's gonna be something Facebook related. They're killing their 2.2 api, I guess, today, maybe they messed up something. :/

Comment: Oh ok , because yesterday i let the code work fine, it look like a Facebook related.

Comment: Yeah, composer update fixed the issue. :)
Guess something in the FBs end was changed, but the update was fast, that's good. :)
thx